# opencv face recognition tutorial code not working with opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

i am trying to use the code given in the tutorial but it is not working. i am sure all the dependencies are there and the program is compiling but it giving me some errors related that some functions can not be found.

here is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static Mat norm_0_255(InputArray _src){

    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    Mat dst;
    switch(src.channels()){
    case 1:
        cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
        break;
    case 3:
        cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC3);
        break;
    default:
        src.copyTo(dst);
        break;
    }
    return dst;
}

static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';'){
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if(!file){
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while(getline(file, line)){
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);
        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()){
            images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

    if(argc < 2){
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <csv.ext> <output_folder> " << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    string output_folder = ".";
    if(argc == 3){
        output_folder = string(argv[2]);
    }

    string fn_csv = string(argv[1]);

    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> labels;

    try{
        read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
    }catch(cv::Exception& e){
        cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if(images.size() <= 1){
        string error_message = "This demo needs at least 2 images to work. please add more images to your data set!";
        CV_Error(CV_StsError, error_message);
    }

    int height = images[0].rows;

    Mat testSample = images[images.size() - 1];
    int testLabel = labels[labels.size() - 1];
    images.pop_back();
    labels.pop_back();

    Ptr<cv::face::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::face::createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);

    int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);

    string result_message = format("Predicted class = %d / Actual class = %d ", predictedLabel, testLabel);
    cout << result_message << endl;

    Mat eigenvalues = model->getMat("eigenvalues");
    Mat W = model->getMat("eigenvectors");
    Mat mean = model->getMat("mean");

    if(argc == 2){
        imshow("mean", norm_0_255(mean.reshape(1, images[0].rows)));
    }else{
        imwrite(format("%s/mean.png", output_folder.c_str()), norm_0_255(mean.reshape(1, images[0].rows)));
    }

      // Display or save the Eigenfaces:
    for (int i = 0; i < min(10, W.cols); i++) {
        string msg = format("Eigenvalue #%d = %.5f", i, eigenvalues.at<double>(i));
        cout << msg << endl;
        // get eigenvector #i
        Mat ev = W.col(i).clone();
        // Reshape to original size & normalize to [0...255] for imshow.
        Mat grayscale = norm_0_255(ev.reshape(1, height));
        // Show the image & apply a Jet colormap for better sensing.
        Mat cgrayscale;
        applyColorMap(grayscale, cgrayscale, COLORMAP_JET);
        // Display or save:
        if(argc == 2) {
            imshow(format("eigenface_%d", i), cgrayscale);
        } else {
            imwrite(format("%s/eigenface_%d.png", output_folder.c_str(), i), norm_0_255(cgrayscale));
        }
    }

    // Display or save the image reconstruction at some predefined steps:
    for(int num_components = min(W.cols, 10); num_components < min(W.cols, 300); num_components+=15) {
        // slice the eigenvectors from the model
        Mat evs = Mat(W, Range::all(), Range(0, num_components));
        Mat projection = subspaceProject(evs, mean, images[0].reshape(1,1));
        Mat reconstruction = subspaceReconstruct(evs, mean, projection);
        // Normalize the result:
        reconstruction = norm_0_255(reconstruction.reshape(1, images[0].rows));
        // Display or save:
        if(argc == 2) {
            imshow(format("eigenface_reconstruction_%d", num_components), reconstruction);
        } else {
            imwrite(format("%s/eigenface_reconstruction_%d.png", output_folder.c_str(), num_components), reconstruction);
        }
    }
    // Display if we are not writing to an output folder:
    if(argc == 2) {
        waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(faceReco)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(faceReco faceReco.cpp)
target_link_libraries(faceReco ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Errors:

```
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:110:27: error: ‘class cv::face::FaceRecognizer’ has no member named ‘getMat’
  Mat eigenvalues = model->getMat("eigenvalues");
                           ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:111:17: error: ‘class cv::face::FaceRecognizer’ has no member named ‘getMat’
  Mat W = model->getMat("eigenvectors");
                 ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:112:20: error: ‘class cv::face::FaceRecognizer’ has no member named ‘getMat’
  Mat mean = model->getMat("mean");
                    ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:130:46: error: ‘COLORMAP_JET’ was not declared in this scope
         applyColorMap(grayscale, cgrayscale, COLORMAP_JET);
                                              ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:130:58: error: ‘applyColorMap’ was not declared in this scope
         applyColorMap(grayscale, cgrayscale, COLORMAP_JET);
                                                          ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:143:75: error: ‘subspaceProject’ was not declared in this scope
         Mat projection = subspaceProject(evs, mean, images[0].reshape(1,1));
                                                                           ^
/home/abdulaziz/workspace/OpenCV_Projects/FaceReco/faceReco.cpp:144:71: error: ‘subspaceReconstruct’ was not declared in this scope
         Mat reconstruction = subspaceReconstruct(evs, mean, projection);
                                                                       ^
```

Comment: please update your opencv_contrib repo. the samples [were fixed](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face/samples) some days ago.

Comment: @berak thank you, that worked for me :D